# Use py2app to package pyside program error include imageformats plugins

Tags: pyside, py2app

setup.py

```
APP = ['systray.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'includes': ['djmemori.settings'],
           'packages': ['django', 'south'],
           'qt_plugins': 'imageformats' # if I comment out this line, python setup.py py2app will success
           }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

python setup.py py2app

```
...
copying file /Users/teamx/workspace/env-memori-pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/recipes/qt.conf -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt.conf
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib
copying file /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib
copying file /.dbfseventsd -> /Users/teamx/workspace/memori_pc/src/djmemori/dist/systray.app/Contents/Resources/qt_plugins/imageformats/.dbfseventsd
error: /.dbfseventsd: Operation not supported on socket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code py2app/recipes/pyside.py:21

```
    if '*' in item:
        for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(plugin_dir, item)):
            resources.append((os.path.dirname('qt_plugins' + path[len(plugin_dir):]), [path]))
        else:
            resources.append((os.path.dirname(os.path.join('qt_plugins', item)), os.path.join(plugin_dir, item)))
```

to

```
    if '*' in item:
        for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(plugin_dir, item)):
            resources.append((os.path.dirname('qt_plugins' + path[len(plugin_dir):]), [path]))
    else:
        resources.append((os.path.dirname(os.path.join('qt_plugins', item)), os.path.join(plugin_dir, item)))
```

can resolve this problem.

The code indent problem will cause py2app add a resource:

('qt_plugins/imageformats', u'/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/*') # note that the second item of the tuple should be a list, but it's a string here

And then in py2app/build_app.py:598

```
def iter_data_files(self):
    dist = self.distribution
    allres = chain(getattr(dist, 'data_files', ()) or (), self.resources)
    for (path, files) in (normalize_data_file(fn) for fn in allres):
        path = fsencoding(path)
        for fn in files:                      # <-- this line
            fn = fsencoding(fn)
            yield fn, os.path.join(path, os.path.basename(fn))
```

files should be a list, but now, it's a string: u'/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats/*'
This will cause py2app to copy files in path: '/', 'D', 'e', 'v', ...
So py2app begin to iterate root path '/', when it encouter /.dbfseventsd, it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in py2app. Could you check for me if there is a file named ".dbfseventsd" in "/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats" (or a symlink that points to that file)?

Also, please file an issue at https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app to ensure I don't forget to actually fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, Ronald Oussoren, there seems no ".dbfseventsd" in "/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats". But there is one in root path.

Comment: How did you install PySide and Qt? Did you use the binaries referenced from <http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX>?

Comment: Yes, I installed PySide and Qt from that link. @Ronald Oussoren.